# Meteor unable to start Mongo server on windows 8.1

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, meteor

so I was trying to learn Meteor.js. I installed Chocolaty on my windows 8.1 machine, and with the command **choco install meteor**, I was able to successfully install meteor using Windows Powershell.
I created a new meteor project using the command **meteor create demo** and started the project using **meteor** command. Here's where I get Mongo server error, which says-

```
Unexpected mongo exit code 3221225781. Restarting.
Can't start Mongo server.
```

The server never starts and the process exits.
I tried uninstalling meteor and reinstalling with the same command as I mentioned above, but I am still facing the same error.
Please help.

Comment: MongoDB is installed and on your PATH variable or not?

Comment: 3221225781 in hex is 0xC0000135,which looks a lot like a windows error code

Comment: @VedantBang I have not installed MongoDB locally. Do I need to install it?

Comment: Oh yes, you will have to install MongoDB locally, if you are using a local database.